# Assign feature number based on the continuation of Date of occurrence in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

In a data frame, `dt` how to assign feature number that changes with change in Date. I.e., in `dt` we have multiple grid points but two features separated by gaps in Date as can be visibly seen in this plot (Feature 1 from 2018-06-20 to 208-06-21 and Feature 2 from 2018-06-28 to 2018-06-29). [image]. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238734/assign-event-number-based-on-date-of-occurece-in-r-dataframe) answer provides the solution for a somehow similar problem but for a single point. So my question is: how to count/identify the Date column without gap and assign say Feature1 for all the first set of Dates without gap and so on.

```
dt<-structure(list(x = c(228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 
 236, 237, 238, 231, 232, 233, 234, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 
235, 236, 237, 238, 231, 232, 233, 234, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 
216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 
218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 
219, 220, 221, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 
221, 222, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 
211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222), 
y = c(47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 
47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46), Date = structure(c(17702, 
 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
17703, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 
17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 
17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17709, 17710, 17710, 17710, 
17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 
17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 
17710, 17710, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 
17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 
17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711, 17711), class = "Date"), 
val = c(62.24, 65.06, 67.92, 70.82, 73.73, 76.53, 78.24, 
78.43, 77.09, 75.11, 72.98, 63.98, 66.96, 70.01, 72.17, 61.76, 
 64.68, 67.59, 70.54, 73.32, 74.82, 74.69, 73.12, 70.82, 67.7, 
64.64, 67.71, 70.72, 72.68, 73.58, 78.25, 81.23, 82.79, 83.07, 
 82.2, 80.49, 78.08, 74.86, 70.71, 65.61, 81.85, 86.05, 88.58, 
 89.59, 89.28, 88, 85.91, 83.3, 80.11, 75.96, 70.66, 64.46, 
 79.09, 84.56, 88.64, 91.44, 92.76, 92.59, 91.25, 88.95, 85.7, 
 81.46, 76.27, 93.98, 99.09, 102.71, 104.84, 105.43, 104.74, 
102.94, 100.19, 96.49, 91.73, 85.89, 79.15, 94.49, 99.93, 
 103.71, 106.07, 106.84, 106.05, 103.97, 100.82, 96.62, 91.38, 
 85.14, 110.63, 115.91, 119.45, 121.3, 121.52, 120.44, 118.22, 
 114.87, 110.35, 104.58, 97.59, 89.61)), row.names = c(NA, 
-98L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(17702, 17703, 
 17709, 17710, 17711), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(
1:15, 16:29, 30:52, 53:75, 76:98), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
dt
plt<-ggplot(dt,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=val))+
  facet_wrap(~Date)
plt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your expectation and final, desired output. However, it sounds like you want to identify features based on gap in dates. In particular, the gap of more than one day would separate features. If that is true, you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(feature = c(1, cumsum(diff(Date) > 1) + 1))
```

In short, this will determine the cumulative sum of when there is a difference between rows in `Date` of more than one (this occurs with gaps in dates of greater than 1). With your example, this will add a `feature` column to your data, with value of 1 for all rows with dates of 6-20 through 6-21, and value of 2 for the other rows from 6-27 through 6-29.